# PHP array keys to a string

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I have an array that looks something like this

> Array ( [0] => T [1] => T [2] => T [3] => T [4] => T [5] => T [6] => T [7] => T [8] => T [9] => T [10] => T [11] => T [12] => T [13] => T [14] => T [15] => T [16] => T [17] => T [18] => T [19] => T [20] => T [21] => T [22] => T [23] => T [24] => T [25] => T [26] => T [27] => T [28] => T [29] => T [30] => T [31] => T [32] => T [33] => T [34] => T [35] => T [36] => T [37] => T [38] => T [39] => T [40] => T [41] => T [42] => T [43] => T [44] => T [45] => T [46] => T [47] => T [48] => T [49] => T [50] => T [51] => T [52] => T [53] => T [54] => T [55] => T [56] => T [57] => T [58] => T [59] => T [60] => T [61] => T [62] => T [63] => T [64] => T [65] => T [66] => T [67] => T [68] => T [69] => T [70] => T [71] => T [72] => 0 [73] => 0 [74] => 0 [75] => 0 [76] => 0 [77] => 0 [78] => 0 [79] => 0 [80] => 0 [81] => 0 [82] => 0 [83] => 0 [84] => 0 [85] => 0 [86] => 0 [87] => 0 [88] => 0 [89] => 0 [90] => 0 [91] => 0 [92] => 0 [93] => 0 [94] => 0 [95] => 0 [96] => 0 [97] => 0 [98] => 0 [99] => 0 )

What I need to do is group keys [0]-[49], [50]-[99], and [100]-[149] into three string variables so tht they can be inserted into the database fields 'answ1-50', 'answ51-100', and 'answ101-150. Im a little bit lost on this one as I am still somewhat of a php novice. How do i break up this array into three groups as a string?

Comment: Oh please don't do that - you should store each answer as it's own row. Google "normalization"

Comment: what is the logic behind what you are doing?

Comment: What you want to do is bad practice, but if you *really* want to do it, look at [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode).  What you *should* do is insert each as its own row; you shouldn't store more than one value in one field in a database.

Comment: this is for a quiz/test. I'm storing the answers into an array as a SESSION variable so that the information can be used in multiple places and purposes. the answers have to be stored in the database as groups of 50 because that is the way the script that processes the test result score is written. happens to be a script i dont have access to, so no changing that.

Comment: maybe i miss stated my self. the database requirement is to have a string of 50 characters (answers)...so it is one value that is being stored. the script later looks for specific answers at specific string positions.

Comment: @RocketHazmat -- for his purposes, this is not necessarily "bad practice" (nor necessarily "good practice"). $string[$pos] would make for fast lookup, and would not have the overhead of storing 150 values in a database (for each test).

Comment: you mean 50 character is the same as 50 answers or that each question can be up to 50 characters? @SandraWillford

Comment: @JacobS: Now that we know his goal, it's not a horrible idea, no. :-P

Comment: @RocketHazmat && JacobS - This test is for a substance abuse evaluation, and any given answer may or may not be evaluated under multiple conditions. There are a total of 20 evaluations of the test answer some of the evaluations are based on the group of 50 answers, and some on the individual answer. Placing each individual answer as its own row is extremely inefficient, not only in the database setup, but also in the script. You pretty much nailed it.

Answer (score 2):

While not good practice, the answer to your posted question is to:

```
list($group1, $group2, $group3) = array_map("implode", array_chunk($arr, 50));
```

(assumes that you always have 150 answers. if you don't, skip the list and you will have an array of results $groups[0], $groups[1], $groups[2])

Comment: Assuming you know there will be 3 groups.

Comment: Yes -- I was in the process of editing to add exactly that, but thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to do this, but this should do the trick.

```
//assuming content in $myarray
$newarr = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($myarray); $i++ {
    $j = floor($i / 50);
    if($j == $i / 50) {
        $newarr[$j] = "";
    }
    $newarr[$j] += (string)$myarray[$i]; 
}
```

Each element of $newarr should be a string with 50 answers in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply write it under the loop and concatenate the values to a string.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($yourarray); $i++) {
if(i>=0 && $i<50)
{
    $str1=$str1.$yourarray[i];
}
else if(i>=50 && $i<100)
{
    $str2=$str2.$yourarray[i];
}
else if(i>=100 && $i<150)
{
    $str3=$str3.$yourarray[i];
}}
```